# How do you change a html text after form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to create a form and based on the inputs of the form, I want to give out a result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
        <title>Plan <B></B></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Plan B</h1>
        <form onsubmit="return processInputs()">
            <label for="tnumber">Team Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="tnumber" name="tnumber"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <p>Results:</p>
        <p id="results">something</p>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Processing Inputs
        function processInputs(){
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "77%";
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

Above, I am obtaining inputs from the data by making a form attribute. When the user submits the form, I want the text of the "id=results" (in this case, it is "something") to change. So for now, I wanted that text to change to "77%".

However, upon the submission of the form, the code does not seem to work. Are there any ways of fixing this code?

Thanks.

Comment: `<form onsubmit="processInputs()">` You don't return the function on submit just invoke it

Comment: I tried invoking the method, but it still did work...Like the "something" text gets changed to "77%" text for a second, and it goes back to "something" text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return false` to the `processInputs()` function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
        <title>Plan <B></B></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Plan B</h1>
        <form onsubmit="return processInputs()">
            <label for="tnumber">Team Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="tnumber" name="tnumber"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <p>Results:</p>
        <p id="results">something</p>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Processing Inputs
        function processInputs(){
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "77%";
            return false;
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Although this fixes the issue If you expect the function to return if the validation of the form is successful you have to return `true`. By returning a `false`  in this case the form  is not been validated and will stop from submitting.